# How can I merge these 2 objects into 1?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects:

```
var set1 = {
    name: "2020-02-17T00:00:00",
    series: [
        { key: "055", value: 1154.47},
        { key: "056", value: 4132.2},
        { key: "059", value: 1825.33}
    ]
}

var set2 = {
    startdate: "2020-02-17T00:00:00",
    series: [
        {key: "005",value: 0},
        {key: "055",value: 0},
        {key: "056",value: 0},
        {key: "059",value: 0},
        {key: "042",value: 0},
        {key: "M002",value: 0}
    ]
}
```

How can I push the values of set1 onto set2 without overwriting any of the keys with value 0 as such:

```
var set2 = {
    startdate: "2020-02-17T00:00:00",
    series: [
        {key: "005", value: 0},
        {key: "055", value: 1154.47},
        {key: "056", value: 4132.2},
        {key: "059", value: 1825.33},
        {key: "042", value: 0},
        {key: "M002", value: 0}
    ]
}
```

Relevant code, you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/xLr8qoes/1/

Comment: You'll have to loop into the array and update the value accordingly.

Comment: Your jsfiddle isn't helping. It's not an adequate response to your bug being closed for lack of clarity or focus because it's the same code repeated so a waste of time. I seriously doubt there's any built-in language function or operation that would merge to that level of nesting and specificity so @reflexgravity is right, you'll have to iterate through the first array to get items to merge in, and then feed them to another iteration that looks for a key match in the 2nd array and if found, updates the value, and if not found adds the new key-value pair to the 2nd array.

Comment: I sort of disagree that this question should have been closed because it's not really lacking clarity or focus, it's asking for help with a pretty simple technique and that is not outside the scope of what StackOverflow purports to do. If it was open I would provide an answer that explains it, thus I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

```
set2.series = [ ...set2.series, ...set1.series ];
```

This will set set2 series to be

```
[
  {
    "key": "005",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "key": "055",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "key": "056",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "key": "059",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "key": "042",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "key": "M002",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "key": "055",
    "value": 1154.47
  },
  {
    "key": "056",
    "value": 4132.2
  },
  {
    "key": "059",
    "value": 1825.33
  },
  {
    "key": "055",
    "value": 1154.47
  },
  {
    "key": "056",
    "value": 4132.2
  },
  {
    "key": "059",
    "value": 1825.33
  }
]
```

Comment: He, clever. I wasn't aware of the JavaScript spread syntax operator, but it looks like that would probably work. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work out a way in the end!

```
set2.series.forEach(element => {
    if (set1.series.filter(e => e.key == element.key).length >= 1){
        element.value = set1.series.filter(e => e.key == element.key)[0].value;
    }
    else element.value = 0;
})
```

For each object in set2.series it filters set1.series on matching keys. Filter returns an array so if length of array is > 0, that key/value pair exists in set1.

```
set2 = {
    "startdate": "2020-02-17T00:00:00",
    "series": [
        {key: "005", value: 0}, 
        {key: "042", value: 0}, 
        {key: "055", value: 1154.47}, 
        {key: "056", value: 4132.2}, 
        {key: "059", value: 1825.33}, 
        {key: "M002", value: 0}
    ]
}
```

Is there a better/simpler way than this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in both way

Using spread operator:

> let object3=[...object1,...object2]

Using Older javascript:

> let returnedTarget = Object.assign({},object1, object2);